# Помощь в использовании API Облачной АТС Билайн

Tags: веб-служба, облако, телефония

Не могу начать использовать. Техподдержки в Билайне нет по этому продукту.

что указывать в subscriberId и targetId при подписке на события?

Вроде бы указываю пользователя ID, приходит UID подписки на события в результате запроса, но когда событие возникает - не вызывается callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Создайте подписку без указания pattern, таким образом она будет реагировать на все номера
2. При создании подписки вы получите subscriberId, сделайте GET запрос и если подписка создалась успешно вы получите информацию о ней
3. URL который вы указали при создании подписки должен возвращать код 200, иначе подписка аннулируется